# Joining two tables using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables:

> PlanMaster (PlanName, Product_ID)

and

> ProductPoints (Entity_ID, Product_ID, Comm1, Comm2)

Now I am storing Entity_ID into a Session which is stored into an 'int':

```
int getEntity = Int16.Parse(Session["EntitySelected"].ToString());
```

I want to show in my LINQ query all of the items from above tables which has

> Entity_ID = getEntity

Here is my LINQ query:

```
var td = from s in cv.Entity_Product_Points join r in dt.PlanMasters on s.Product_ID equals r.Product_ID
         where s.Entity_ID = getEntity
         select s;
```

Now its giving me an error which says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'bool'

What is going wrong here? Thank you for your comments in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
 where s.Entity_ID == getEntity
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var td =
    from s in cv.Entity_Product_Points
    join r in dt.PlanMasters on s.Product_ID equals r.Product_ID
    where s.Entity_ID == getEntity
    select s;
```

`=` not equal to `==`

Answer (score 5):

`where s.Entity_ID = getEntity` should be `where s.Entity_ID == getEntity`.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that be a double equals?

Answer (score 4):

```
var db1 = (from a in AccYearEntity.OBLHManifests select a).ToList();
var db2 = (from a in MasterEntity.UserMasters select a).ToList();

var query = (from a in db1
             join b in db2 on a.EnteredBy equals b.UserId
             where a.LHManifestNum == LHManifestNum
             select new { LHManifestId = a.LHManifestId, LHManifestNum = a.LHManifestNum, LHManifestDate = a.LHManifestDate, StnCode = a.StnCode, Operatr = b.UserName }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please provide a description to your solution.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will do,

where s.Entity_ID == getEntity