# Linq - how to filter dataset based on data in another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm looking to filter the data in a dataset much like you'd do a `where <value> in (select <value> from other_table where year=2016)`

So I have a list of the "values":

```
var BUs = (from b in dc.BusinessUnits
where b.Year == int.Parse(ddlYears.SelectedValue)
orderby b.BuName
select new { b.BUID }).ToList();
```

So what I need to do is filter this dataset based on the BUID list returned in the BUs var.

```
IQueryable<Market> markets = (from p in dc.Markets
orderby p.MarketName
select p);
```

Help? I'm 100% new to linq so I need a concise solution.

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571861/joining-two-tables-using-linq

Answer (score 0):

Well if you `Market` entity has a `BUID` property and this property it's a primitive type (`int`, `string`..) or an `enum`, you can use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338641(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var BUs = (from b in dc.BusinessUnits
           where b.Year == int.Parse(ddlYears.SelectedValue)
           orderby b.BuName
           select  b.BUID );

IQueryable<Market> markets = (from p in dc.Markets
                              where BUs.Contains(p.BUID)
                              orderby p.MarketName
                              select p);
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of filtering by in memory id list is to use [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) method. But you need first to make sure your list contains ids - they way you wrote it it will contain anonymous type with a property called `BUID`, by changing the first query like this

```
int year = int.Parse(ddlYears.SelectedValue);
var BUIDs = (from b in dc.BusinessUnits
where b.Year == year
orderby b.BuName
select b.BUID).ToList();
```

and then use

```
var markets = (from p in dc.Markets
               where BUIDs.Contains(p.BUID)   
               orderby p.MarketName
               select p);
```

But note that this will be inefficient. Much better option would be to not use the list of BUIDs for filtering, but combining the 2 queries so the whole thing becomes a single query executed in the database, like this

```
var markets = (from p in dc.Markets
               where dc.BusinessUnits.Any(bu => b.Year == year && b.BUID == p.BUID)
               orderby p.MarketName
               select p);
```

This is the exact equivalent of, if using your words, *much like you'd do a "where in (select from other_table where year=2016)"*.

Comment: your last query is not good for performance. Better is first to load all data to BuidList, then create new query for predicate with BuidList.Contains(p=>p.Buid)

Comment: Well, I said, it's a direct equivalent of how you would write it in SQL.

Comment: Ye, for better solution in my opinion: change order in predicate for Any(...). Like this: b.BUID == p.BUID && b.Year == year

Comment: @W92 This are techniques from 10-15 years ago. Todays query optimizers absolutely don't care how you write the SQL. And btw, I doubt the first query is better - it would generate something like `IN (....)` with potentially big list inside, while the second will most probably generate a join.

Comment: I assumed that BUID is indexed column and it should be taken in consideration :-)