# Making 1 table join on 2 other tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to join 1 table onto 2 other tables with LINQ, but I can't seem to figure out how this is done.

I can make it work writing pure SQL statements within Visual studio, I'm just not sure how to convert this into LINQ.

Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, pw.Number, pc.Number FROM Customers as c
LEFT JOIN Tasks as k ON k.Id = c.Task_Id
LEFT JOIN Workers as w ON w.Id = k.Worker_Id
LEFT JOIN PersonNumbers as pw ON pw.Person_Id = w.Id
LEFT JOIN Chiefs as ch ON ch.Id = k.Chief_Id
LEFT JOIN PersonNumbers as pc ON pc.Person_Id = ch.Id
```

Perhaps this requires a bit of explanation.

We have a bunch of **Customers** and these customers can have some **tasks**. Within a task you will have **workers** and **chiefs**. Within the **PersonNumbers** table, I have some extra information about **workers** and **chiefs**, and this is the information that I need.

Comment: This is an easy query, you should be able to write it in linq using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx).

Comment: A similar implementation check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571861/joining-two-tables-using-linq

Comment: You can use `join` in Linq, but it's better to use navigation properties assuming that your entities have them. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Your join is redundant. Instead you can do like                          `SELECT c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, pw.Number, pc.Number FROM Customers as c
LEFT JOIN Tasks as k ON k.Id = c.Task_Id
LEFT JOIN Workers as w ON w.Id = k.Worker_Id
LEFT JOIN Chiefs as ch ON ch.Id = k.Chief_Id
LEFT JOIN PersonNumbers as pc ON pc.Person_Id = ch.Id and pw.Person_Id=w.id`

Comment: Do have these values transformed into entities. Because doing them would facilitate Linq joins.

Comment: @juharr If you can closely look PersonNumbers is used twice. I have removed that redundant join

Comment: @KrishnaPS That's a completely different query.  Currently they are getting two sets of persons via the workes and chiefs, but you are getting one set of persons that are related to both the workers and chiefs.  Your query wouldn't even work because there isn't a `pw` now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like the following assuming all your joins are based on foreign keys that should result in navigation properties in your entities.  The `DefaultIfEmpty` is what makes everything a left join.

```
var results = from c in db.Customers
              from k in c.Tasks.DefaultIfEmpty()
              from w in k.Workers.DefaultIfEmpty()
              from pw in w.Persons.DefaultIfEmpty()
              from ch in k.Chiefs.DefaultIfEmpty()
              from pc in ch.Persons.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  c.CustomerId, 
                  c.CustomerName, 
                  pw.Number, 
                  pc.Number
              };
```

If you don't have the navigation properties then you'll have to use `join`.

```
var results = from c in db.Customers
              join xk in db.Tasks on xk.Id equals c.Task_Id 
              from k in xk.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join xw in db.Workers on xw.Id equals k.Worker_Id
              from w in xw.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join xpw in db.Persons on xpw.Person_Id equals w.Id 
              from pw in xpw.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join xch in db.Chiefs on xch.Id equals k.Chief_Id 
              from ch in xch.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join xpc in db.Persons on xpc.Person_Id euals ch.Id
              from pc in xpc.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  c.CustomerId, 
                  c.CustomerName, 
                  pw.Number, 
                  pc.Number
              };
```